# Convert .obj to .js files

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have gone through different three.js examples. Some of the examples uses .js or .bin files instead of .obj files. e.g. used in webgl_materials_cars.html example. How do I get .js file for my .obj file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/).
[Converter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/converters/obj/convert_obj_three.py).
[Blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender).
[Clara.io](https://clara.io/).
Various other [converters and exporters](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils)

Comment: 2pha: thanks for your answer. I tried this(the link given) converter and its converting .obj to .js files: https://github.com/theMaxscriptGuy/Windows_Programs/tree/master/Obj_To_ThreeJS

Comment: 2pha: could you please tell me how do I use clara.io to export a model in a .json file, if you are knowing that?

Comment: I am not sure as I do not use it. I just read a while ago that it could be done.

Comment: please accept the answer if it answers your original question